# How to print out a pointer string's length for C programming language?

Tags: c, pointers, c-strings

I am using the C programming language, and I need to print out a pointer string's length. I tried `sizeof` and `strlen` but both did not work because I am using a pointer string.

This is my main function:

```
char userInput[100], *split[NPTR] = { NULL }, **p = split;
...
while (*p)
          execute(*p++);
```

And here is my execute function:

```
int i = 0;
// Array *history;
void execute(char *p)
{
  printf(strlen(p));
}
```

Comment: The first argument to printf is a format string. For example: “%d”

Comment: Thank you for your comment. is there any way to print the length of the string by any change?

Comment: The `while (*p)` does not execute as `*p == NULL`, therefore no printing via `execute(char *p)`.  Better to post a [mcve].

Comment: The phrase "pointer string" doesn't make sense. A *string* is by definition "a contiguous sequence of characters terminated by and including the first null character". A *pointer to a string* is by definition "a pointer to its initial (lowest addressed) character".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
printf("%zu\n", strlen(p));
```

`printf` needs a format specifier to know what the type of the `strlen(p)` is

Comment: Format should be `%zu` for `size_t` returned from `strlen`

Comment: ... also should print a separator as this is called from a loop